# My login function is unable to match username and password stored in the database

Tags: php, password-hash

This code always returns  wrong username and password though its right and same function works for my admin login system. It worked some time ago, and now it won't.

```
function login($user,$pass,$accountType){
require('connection.php');

$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * From $accountType");
    $regex="/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/";
    if(preg_match($regex, $user)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $username=$row['username'];
                $password=$row['password'];
                if($user==$username){   
                        if (password_verify($pass,$password)){                               
                            if($accountType=='student'){
                                $_SESSION['student']='$user';
                                header('Location:studentprofile.php');

                                exit();
                            }
                            elseif($accountType=='teacher'){
                                $_SESSION['student']='$user';
                                header('Location:teacherprofile.php');
                                exit();
                                }
                            elseif($accountType=='admin'){
                                header('Location:admin.html');
                                exit();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $_SESSION['error']="wrong password"."<br>";
                        }
                }
                else{
                    $_SESSION['error']="Wrong username "."<br>";
                }   
            }

        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['error']="No data found";
        }
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['error']="not a valid email,";
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the code for password_verify($password)? Wouldn't make more sense to check for the user and the password already in the query instead of selecting ALL users?

Comment: @Alberto http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: So you're saying that you are already this exact code to authenticate admin users, but it doesn't work if the userType is teacher or student. There could be something wrong with the data stored in the database, maybe the hash is invalid...

Comment: How large is the column storing the password? It needs to be 60 or more characters wide to store the hash properly. Are you getting any errors? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: yeah it might be but i can't find it by myself. Thankyou for you reply@Alberto

Comment: the code is in line 12 and i don;t think selecting all from account type creates problem because its working for admin. $accountType store a specific account. It doesnot retrieve data of all table $accountype specifies which table to retrieve data from. thanks for suggestion. @JayBlanchard

Comment: ohh i have specified varchar(20) for storing password in the database is error there with size of column ? @JayBlanchard

Comment: YES! `varchar(20)` is not large enough. Change it to `varchar(254)` and re-register the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314752/my-login-function-is-unable-to-match-username-and-password-stored-in-the-databas?noredirect=1#comment91577953_52314752) *"i have specified varchar(20) for storing password in the database"*

The password field should be large. The `password_hash()` can generate some very lengthy text (**the current default is 60 characters**), so making the field larger, such as `varchar(254)` or `text`  will allow for the length needed. The PHP team is adding more algorithms to the method which means the hash can and will grow. We also do not want to limit our user's ability to use the password or passphrase of their choice. It's best to leave room for the change